# Assign a new instance to a span variable in loop

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<char> span = "LOW:0:V:7878".AsSpan();
int index;
while ((index = span.IndexOf(':')) != -1)
{
    span = span.Slice(index);
}
```

This span variable is always same as `":0:V:7878"`. But I tried it works when not in a loop:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<char> span = "LOW:0:V:7878".AsSpan();
span = span.Slice(3);
span = span.Slice(2);
```

I am confused.

Comment: What is expectation? Please Give little more clarity

Comment: If you could tell the expected output, we can then tweak your loop accordingly or use any other logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because after the first execution of the loop the value of span is "**:0:V:7878**" and hereafter the index that you would get is 0 and hence splice won't go to the next place.

[image]